# How do i add custom class to "Create account " header link and how to rename it label as "Open an Account" in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.1, create-account, headerlink

How do I add a custom class to "Create account "  header link

and how to rename it label as "Open an Account" in Magento 2

Please refer the attachments

[image]

[image]

Can anyone guide me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add this in your `default.xml` file inside `body` tag

```
<referenceBlock name="register-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Open an Account</argument>
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">test-class</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

**Update :**

Add this in `default.xml` file

```
<referenceBlock name="register-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::openaccount.phtml</argument>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Open an Account</argument>
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="true">new-account-class</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Create new phtml file `openaccount.phtml` in your module/theme and add this content

```
<li class="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getClass());?>">
    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getHref());?>">
        <?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getLabel());?>
    </a>
</li>
```

For Updated answer I followed [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) answer with some changes.

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 3):

By default you cannot add attributes on the `li` element. Only on the `a` element inside it.
But there is a workaround. you can specify to the block that renders the "create account" link a template. In this template you can do whatever you want.

SO add this in one of your custom modules in `view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="register-link" template="[Vendor]_[Module]::register.phtml" />
```

then create the file `view/frontend/templates/register.phtml` with this content:

```
<li class="my-awesome-class">
    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getHref());?>">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Open an Account'));?>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi @Marius, works fine